# Azure Windows VM Monitoring "% Committed Bytes In Use" issue

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Has anyone configured Azure windows VM percentage memory usage? I have tried some of the solutions and configured `% Committed Bytes In Use` but actually this is not what is actual RAM usage of VM. It is `\ Committed Bytes to the Memory \ Commit Limit`.This is not what i needed because even my VM memory(RAM) is at 90% my `% Committed Bytes In Use` is shows around 60 to 65% but i set a alert rule at 70%.

Can any one tell me how i will get actual memory(RAM) usage so that when my VM memory goes above 70 i can alerted but not `% Committed Bytes In Use`.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/28742dfb-e550-498f-b6d2-0ca717b945d0/memory-percentage-metric-missing-other-metrics-displaying-odd-names?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT  thanks for the update, As i said earlier i have already tried that it is showing  "% Committed Bytes In Use" ,but its not actual RAM usage of server at some moment when your RAM usage reaches 100% then  "% Committed Bytes In Use"  line goes flat to 66.96% it never increases.so as i said i created alert for 70% then in this case i never gets alert.

Comment: Take a look at [Memory percent committed memory in use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring/infrastructure-health/vmhealth-windows/winserver-memory-pctcommitted) and [Memory available megabytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring/infrastructure-health/vmhealth-windows/winserver-memory-availmbytes). Maybe you can choose an appropriate one to achieve what you want.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT It doesn't help,i want alert to be triggered incase of my AZURE VM RAM utilization goes high.But Currently there is no metrics that tells that.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT It doesn't help,i want alert to be triggered incase of my AZURE VM RAM utilization goes high.But Currently there is no metrics that tells that. Only available metrics are "% Committed Bytes In Use" which is for pagefile(Virtual Memory) not for RAM usage.  And second one is "Memory available megabytes" this is not so usefull untill you explicitly set your VM total memory in query and do some math to get percentage usege to trigger alert for 70% of usage. Think if i have 100 VM in Azure i need to have total memory of all server to calculate percentage of usage.